# Javascript get UTC out of date and time variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables in javascript like:

time: 02:00
date: 25-08-2017

and I'm wondering if I can put these into a Date() object and get the UTC date and time out of it in hours/minutes using getUTCDay(), getUTCHours() and getUTCMinutes() and place them back in the format I got them.

I can load moment.js for it but if I don't have to it would be nice if I can do it without.

Comment: Is that a local time or UTC time?

Comment: That is local time.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your strings to an ISO 8601 string and use it in the `Date` constructor. From there, you can get whatever data you need

```js
let time = '02:00'
let date = '25-08-2017'

let iso8601Date = date.split('-').reverse().join('-')

let dt = new Date(`${iso8601Date}T${time}`) // will be interpreted as local time

const digitFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})

console.info('Parsed date:', dt)
console.info('UTC date in dd-mm-yyyy:',
  `${digitFormatter.format(dt.getUTCDate())}-${(digitFormatter.format(dt.getUTCMonth() + 1))}-${dt.getUTCFullYear()}`
)
console.info('UTC time:', `${digitFormatter.format(dt.getUTCHours())}:${digitFormatter.format(dt.getUTCMinutes())}`)
```

Comment: That is actually what I'm looking for I think as you create a real Date() object again. I need the digitFormatter or is there another way as well ?

Comment: The formatter is just so you get two-digit numbers under 10 like `08`

Comment: OK, that is great, I need to post them as time fields so I can live without I think.

Comment: But what about the time, you cannot get the UTC for it @ once can you ? (5 min edit didn't work anymore on my previous comment)

Comment: Sure you can, just use `getUTCHours() `, etc

Comment: But as minutes has it's own function, why actually ?

Comment: @YamaKasi I'm not really sure what your question is but I've added a "time" example above

Comment: Yes I understand what you did there, thanks. What I wonder is why I get don't get the summer/winter offset right. I get a UTC on 13.00 of 10.00 which should be 11.00 actually.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about what I discovered, my input was different then 13.00. This does mae a valid question about Dayligt Savings, how to deal with them ?